# reading configuration file entries with dynamic names in python

Tags: python, arrays, variables

i am new to python but already programmed much in PHP. And here is my problem cause both languages use a bit different spelling and usage.
when i want to access a variable in PHP with a dynamic content i can do $array_name[$variable_name]
but how can i do this in python when i do not know the content of $variable_name?

My actual problem:
get a ini entry by variable with dynamic content. In my python script the variable "mode_name" is dynamically filled by an API request. so i do not know the content. The script is checking if this content of "mode_name" is listed in "config/modes" in the ini File. When it is listed, then there is a ini category with the same name and this should be returned in the API request. But see below the code, may be it explains it better.
i shortened the code a bit, cause everything else is working. and the dynamic var gets the correct name ("trafficlight") so it should work (in PHP) but i just getting an error.

python script:

```
import configparser
configfile = 'setup.ini'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(configfile)
if mode_name in config['config']['modes']:
   ret = config[mode_name]
   return jsonify({'mode_name':ret})
```

ini file:

```
[config]
modes = 'trafficlight, record'

[trafficlight]
title = 'trafficlight'
lights = 'red, yellow, green'
gpio_red = 17
gpio_yellow = false
gpio_green = 18

[record]
title = 'recording'
gpio = 17
```

running this ends up in the following error:

```
 File "app.py", line 6
    ret = config[mode_name]
                          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

What am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The indentation on that line is inconsistent; unindent it, then indent it again, or copy the indentation from the other lines.

Comment: indeed, that was the problem... i had tabs as tab and not tab as 4 spaces cause i just used nano to create the file. i really should use an ide! thank you!